# Is there a way to animate objects as one temporarily without "independent movement"?

Tags: animation, groups

I've been working on making a Minecraft Rubik's Cube, and while trying to animate the rotation of a face (with pivot center median) the pieces of the face move independently. Even when they are grouped this happens, and parenting wouldn't work because then I would have to parent every possible side combination just for a turn. Is there any way to move a side as a group without this weird rotation (Sorry I'm not the best in Blender :P)?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Done Turn]

[image: Weird Rotation]

[image: Rubik's Cube]

Comment: so I guess you have 26 cubes? If you parent the whole face (9 cubes) to an empty and rotate this empty, what's the problem? Actually you don't give enough details: what are your minecraft constraints? can you use empties? constraints? are you going to make other animations with the same object? etc...

Comment: Yes each piece is a cube. If I parent this and turn the side, then if I turn a different side intersecting that face, that parent will be including the pieces effected and unaffected by the other turns, and when I turn pieces in that parent, pieces from all over the cube will move. Same thing with empties, if I lock some cubes to the empties, then move a side intersecting those pieces, then those pieces parented to that empty will be scattered about the cube, making the empty useless for any other turns. The Minecraft thing is only the textures.

Comment: The problem is that each of the cubes move independently instead of a group. For example, the Rubik's Cube should allow all 9 cubes on one face to move as one, creating a turn. However, each of the little cubes remember only where to be 30 frames later relative to themselves, and go there ignoring other pieces. Sorry if I was a little confusing back then. What I meant was that if I turn the blue face, and all the blue faces were to be parented to a empty, then that face would turn fine. But if I were to do another turn, I would have to have another empty. I have to do over 100 turns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate a Rubik's cube:

- Join all your cube in the same object with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.
- Put the origin at the center of the object with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*.
- In *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>P</kbd> to *Separate by Loose Parts*. Now all the cubes are separate but they all have the same origin point. It will allow you to rotate them with the same rotation centre.
- In *Object* mode, create an Empty at the same origin point, then select all your cubes and parent them to your Empty with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Object*.
- Put your timeline cursor at frame 0, select all your cubes and press <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*. It will create the initial position of your Rubik's cube.
- Make sure that your Pivot Point (on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of the 3D View) is set on *Median Point*.
- Put your timeline cursor at frame 10, select a face of your rubik's cube (i.e. 9 of your cubes) and rotate it on the X axis. Select all the cubes and Press <kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRotScale*.
- Go on as many times as you want, it should work.

[image]